# How do i add CSS repeat y to make border vertical

Tags: css

Need to align the css generated border vertically...how do i use **background-repeat: repeat-y** here :

```
    .container::after { 
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  content:" ";
  background: 
  radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, white 25%, #535353 26%, gray 40%);
  background-color: gray;
  background-size:50px 100px;
  height:50px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: code from https://codepen.io/KarenN/pen/LpVBzv

Comment: Show an example how it looks now and how you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the vertical values to horizontal values, and vice versa:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px; /* bottom: -50px; */
  top: 0; /* left: 0 */
  width: 50px; /* width: 100% */
  height: 100%; /* height: 50px; */
  content: "";
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 50%, white 45%, #535353 46%, gray 60%);
  background-color: gray;
  background-size: 50px 50px; /* background-size: 50px 100px; */
  background-repeat: repeat-y; /* background-repeat: repeat-x; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked...i can't get hang of how to draw the images using the radial-gradient...any good tutorial ?

Comment: Mainly [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient), Stackoverflow, and trial and error.